# Let $\alpha = \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^4$ and $\beta = \omega^3 + \omega^5 + \omega^6$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\omega$ be a complex number such that $\omega^7 = 1$ and $\omega \neq 1$. Let $\alpha = \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^4$ and $\beta = \omega^3 + \omega^5 + \omega^6$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic
[x^2 + px + q = 0]
for some integers $p$ and $q$. Find the ordered pair $(p,q)$.

---

I got that $p=-1$ but does not know how to go on to finding $q$.  All help is appreciated!

Comment: The question gives you a useful hint by saying that $p,q$ are integers: $\beta = \overline{\alpha}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Observe that

$$
\alpha\beta = \omega^4+\omega^5+\omega^6+3\omega^7+\omega^8+\omega^9+\omega^{10}
            = 2+\omega^4(1+\omega+\omega+\cdots+\omega^6)
$$

Answer (score 2):

method is due to Gauss. This book 1875.  $x^2 + x + 2.$

```
gp-pari to check; note a^8 = a
? x = a + a^2 + a^4
%1 = a^4 + a^2 + a
? q = x^2 + x + 2
%2 = a^8 + 2*a^6 + 2*a^5 + 2*a^4 + 2*a^3 + 2*a^2 + a + 2
?
```

If we switched to one of the real numbers $$ t = \omega + \omega^6, $$ we would have a root of
$$ t^3 + t^2 - 2 t - 1  $$

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг   online at https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false   I can see about half a page at a time there.

Answer (score 0):

$$q=\alpha\beta=3+\sum_{j=1}^6w^j=3+w\frac{w^6-1}{w-1}=3+\frac{1-w}{w-1}=2$$